# Spring Cloud Gateway on Kubernetes discovery locator use pod port instead o service port

Tags: spring-boot, kubernetes, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-kubernetes

i'm implementing an API Gateway on openshift with spring cloud gateway and spring cloud kubernetes discovery.

I started from the project https://github.com/salaboy/s1p_gateway.

My gateway configuration is:

```
cloud:
    gateway:
      discovery:
        locator:
          enabled: true
          url-expression: "'http://'+serviceId+':'+port"
    kubernetes:
      reload:
        enabled: true
        mode: polling
        period: 5000
      discovery:
        service-labels:
           type: "java-api"
```

When i view my /actuator/gateway/routes i can see services discovered:

```
{
   "predicate":"Paths: [/common/**], match trailing slash: true",
   "route_id":"ReactiveCompositeDiscoveryClient_common",
   "filters":[
      "[[RewritePath /common/(?<remaining>.*) = '/${remaining}'], order = 1]"
   ],
   "uri":"http://common:8085",
   "order":0
}
```

**The problem is that *8085* is the targetPort (i.e. pod port) and not the service port:**

```
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: common
  namespace: p4p
  selfLink: /api/v1/namespaces/myspace/services/common
  uid: 1851a76f-4764-11ea-a02c-000d3aa9b693
  resourceVersion: '28657990'
  creationTimestamp: '2020-02-04T15:36:21Z'
  labels:
    app: common
    type: java-api
spec:
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 8080
      targetPort: 8085
  selector:
    app: common
    deploymentconfig: common
  clusterIP: 172.30.7.24
  type: ClusterIP
  sessionAffinity: None
status:
  loadBalancer: {}
```

In order to get API gateway to work i MUST to align pod port and service port, but it sounds quite strange.

Comment: hello, did you solve problem? i take same error when there are multiple instances(pods), but no error when there is one pod.

Comment: Hi, i aligned pod port and service port. Every container starts spring-boot with "-Dserver.port=8080".

Answer (score 0):

Is Ribbon being used? Ribbon's default `spring.cloud.kubernetes.ribbon.mode` is POD. From the [docs](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-kubernetes/reference/html/#ribbon-discovery-in-kubernetes) (quote):

> `spring.cloud.kubernetes.ribbon.mode` supports `POD` and `SERVICE` modes.
>
> - The `POD` mode is to achieve load balancing by obtaining the Pod IP
>     address of Kubernetes and using Ribbon. POD mode uses the load
>     balancing of the Ribbon Does not support Kubernetes load balancing,
>     The traffic policy of Istio is not supported.
> - the `SERVICE` mode is directly based on the service name of the Ribbon.
>     Get The Kubernetes service is concatenated into
>     `service-name.{namespace}.svc.{cluster.domain}:{port}` such as:
>     `demo1.default.svc.cluster.local:8080`. the `SERVICE` mode uses load
>     balancing of the Kubernetes service to support Istio’s traffic policy.

Comment: When i try to call rest api via gateway i get  ```There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
finishConnect(..) failed: Host is unreachable: common/172.30.7.24:8085``` and the service is  ```Name:              common
Type:              ClusterIP
IP:                172.30.7.24
Port:              <unset>  8080/TCP
TargetPort:        8085/TCP
Endpoints:         10.129.3.101:8085
```  It seems uses the service IP and the pod port.  I have also added ```spring.cloud.kubernetes.ribbon.mode=SERVICE``` but nothing has changed.

Answer (score 0):

Why cannot you simply set `Service port (port)` to `8085` so it exposes the same port as `Pod` does ? Nothing actually prevents you from doing so.

> When i try to call rest api via gateway i get
>
> ```
> There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500). finishConnect(..) failed: Host is unreachable: common/172.30.7.24:8085
> ```
>
> and the service is
>
> ```
> Name: common Type: ClusterIP IP: 172.30.7.24 Port: <unset> 8080/TCP TargetPort: 8085/TCP Endpoints: 10.129.3.101:8085
> ```
>
> It seems uses the service IP and the pod port. I have also added 
>   `spring.cloud.kubernetes.ribbon.mode=SERVICE` but nothing has changed.

From what you posted it looks like when you're trying to call your rest api via gateway it expects it to be exposed using your `Service` IP (`172.30.7.24`) and port `8085`, so simply expose it on that port and it should work fine:

```
...
spec:
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 8085
      targetPort: 8085
...
```

Please let me know if it helps.

Comment: This is exactly how the question ends: "...In order to get API gateway to work i MUST to align pod port and service port, but it sounds quite strange".

Comment: Yes, I noticed that and I'm asking why it sounds strange because for me there is nothing strange in exposing via `Service` the right port that is expected by api client ? Could you explain it ?

Comment: No, I can't explain it. It could be a bug, I guess, but haven't had a chance to look into the code (there were issues some time ago with multiple ports - only the first was picked...if I remember). So, setting `port` and `targetPort` to be the same could be a workaround, I agree.